# Most suitable stat test for this data?

Tags: anova, generalized-linear-model, friedman-test, minitab

Looking for a difference between: count and size, exposure, animal and colour (CountXsizeXexposureXanimalXcolour).

[image]

There are 480 data in each column of which:

240 each - size (0.5mm and 2mm)

240 each - expo (BF and NBF)

160 each - animal (Anemone, Snail, Shrimp)

120 each - colour (Blue, Black, Red, White)

Data set is non-normal and My data contains replicates (5 per factor)

As my data is not normal I at first thought a friedman test however, I cannot run multiple factors with this stat test and so this isn't any good for me (at least in minitab, which is my only way to run my stats tests). I'm looking for any differences between the multiple factors (this is important to my data) such as: a difference between size, exposure, organism, colour to count. I was also thinking of a general linear model. There are a lot of tests out there and i've now gotten myself muddle amongst them all.

Are there any recommendations of what test you would run with the factors I specified that is non-parametric or should i use a parametric (please justify why you would think this as I need to also justify this when presenting my data)

Thanks for any help

Comment: What do you want to test?

Comment: I want to look for a difference between all the factors and the number of times they interacted with them (count). I want to look at difference of each as well as difference between them (like an anova does but in a non-parametric way, if there is a test)

Comment: so i would want to know if: 0.5mm blue bf anemones interacted more (count) than 2mm red nbf snail etc I'm wanted to see if any of these factors have cause a difference or a specific preference was seen

Comment: “Count” makes me think Poisson or negative binomial regression.

Comment: Count just refers to how many times did they interact. Ill look into both the Poisson and negative binomial regression though thank you